# Smarty : substr a variable

Tags: smarty

How can I print the first n characters of a smarty variable, e.g. the first 30 characters of {$var}?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use truncate modifier:

```
{$var|truncate:30}
```

More information [here](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl).

Answer (score 31):

Use the PHP function:

```
{$var|substr:0:30}
```

or `mb_substr` for UTF-8 variables:

```
{$var|mb_substr:0:30}
```

Quoting from the [Variable Modifiers](https://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl) section of the documentation:

> **All php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly**, as demonstrated in the example above. However, using php-functions as modifiers has two little pitfalls:
>
> - First - sometimes the order of the function-parameters is not the desirable one. Formatting `$foo` with `{"%2.f"|sprintf:$foo}` actually works, but asks for the more intuitive, like `{$foo|string_format:"%2.f"}` that is provided by the Smarty distribution.
> - Secondly - if `$security` is enabled, all php-functions that are to be used as modifiers have to be declared trusted in the `MODIFIER_FUNCS` element of the `$security_settings` array.
>
> *[bold added]*

This is actually difficult to find in the documentation by searching, which (as of this writing) turns up zero results for "php" or "substr".

Comment: This definitely works, but it's not actually a Smarty function, it's a PHP function that you can access from within Smarty.

Comment: Smarty 4.3 has deprecated using PHP functions as modifiers - https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/813 - you will now need to create/register your own custom modifier to wrap the PHP function if forward compatibility is important. Alternately use a smarty modifier such as |truncate.

Answer (score -3):

Regarding to your problem [Jojo already gave the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4325346/2139671).

You should use truncate modifier:

`{$var|truncate:30}`

But for usability and seo-reaons it would be better to shorten the text via css with [`text-overflow`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) property.
It allows you to print the whole text out to the client but shorten it to a specific width/length and show `...` instead.