# Smarty variable: trim first character

Tags: smarty3

I have a variable that will store a twitter account ***@twitteruser***. I need to strip the **@** from the variable so that I can create a button link going to their twitter account.

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325283/smarty-substr-a-variable

Comment: That didn't help, Paul

Answer (score 2):

If you know the character is the first char, use ltrim. I guess str_replace will search the entire string ;)

```
{$twitterUser|ltrim:'@'}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{$twitterUser|replace:'@':''|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}
```